# I'm trying to implement a rollover into a side menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, hyperlink

```css
.SideMenu1 {                
    padding-top:100px;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    height:100%;  
}

.SideMenu1 a {                       
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s

.XButton {              
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;   /
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {   
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="SideMenu" class="SideMenu1">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="XButton" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>   
  <a href="#">Link1</a><br>
  <a href="#">Link2</a><br>
  <a href="#">Link3</a><br>
  <a href="#">Link4</a><br>
</div>

<span style="font-size:30px; cursor:pointer; font-family:Arial" onclick="openNav()">Woosh</span>   <!This is the Open button!>

<script>
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("SideMenu").style.width = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("SideMenu").style.width = "0";
}
</script>
```

I'm trying to implement a rollover image when a link is hovered over in a side menu but I'm not having any luck.
I want it so when one of the the side menu links is hovered over an image appears beside it, I need 4 separate rollovers one for each link.
I've tried setting classes and using :hover but it doesn't seem to work.
I have attached the CSS and HTML as just the side menu, if some body could tell me what functions to implement I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with css with the `:after` pseudo element. I also added jQuery to this snippet and moved the javascript out into its own file. I did the same with the css. It is best to avoid inline css because when the project gets bigger you will have to dig through and find the inline css vs just going to the global.css file and changing it there.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
 function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("SideMenu").style.width = "100%";
 }

 function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("SideMenu").style.width = "0";
 } 
  
 $(".woosh").on('click', function() {
   openNav();
   
 });
  
});
```

```css
.SideMenu1 {                
    padding-top:100px;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    height:100%;  
}

.SideMenu1 a {                       
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }

.woosh {
  font-size:30px; 
  cursor:pointer; 
  font-family:Arial;
}

#link1:hover {
  background-color: orange;
 }

a:hover {
    position: relative;
}
a:hover:after {
    content: url(https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150); /* no need for qoutes */
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 123px; /* change this value to one that suits you */
    top: 6px; /* change this value to one that suits you */
}

.XButton {              
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;   /
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {   
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="SideMenu" class="SideMenu1">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="XButton" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>   
  <a href="#" id="link1">Link1</a><br>
  <a href="#">Link2</a><br>
  <a href="#">Link3</a><br>
  <a href="#">Link4</a><br>
</div>

<span class="woosh">Woosh</span>   <!This is the Open button!>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I ran the snippet and it all works however it won't run on mine but that's probably just a screw up elsewhere in the code. Thanks for the prompt answer as this was bugging me.

Comment: Look at the script tags and make sure youhave the same exact sources

Comment: Okay I've managed to get it working but I have a couple of issues, I've tried changing the id over from a to Link1 as I want each link to have its own personal image however that hasn't worked. Also when I hover over the close button it goes crazy and starts moving about.